# I updated an App but its failed. Missing type parameter in ProGuard

Tags: android, gson, google-maps-android-api-2, proguard, publish

I updated an application that had almost the same code, in the previously version I didn't have problems in proguard. When I launch the app since AndroidStudio I don't have problems, but When I launch a signed app in some parts of the app can show this error:

```
07-21 14:45:02.156  24372-24372/pe.gob.devida E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parameter.
            at com.google.a.c.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.a.c.a.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at pe.gob.devida.fragments.c.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at pe.gob.devida.fragments.b.a(Unknown Source)
            at pe.gob.devida.fragments.b.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.a.a.a.o.c(Unknown Source)
            at com.a.a.a.o.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.a.a.i.run(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-21 14:45:02.584  24372-32210/pe.gob.devida E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
07-21 14:45:02.588  24372-32210/pe.gob.devida E/Google Maps Android API﹕ In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
    Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
    Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
    API Key: YOUR_KEY_HERE
    Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 9A:69:09:32:33:57:C3:8B:42:35:E7:82:07:6C:F9:DF:82:A0:AD:2B;pe.gob.devida
```

The APIKey exists and "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled

I think the problem is in proguard-rules.pro

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose

-dontwarn pe.gob.devida.**
-dontwarn org.simpleframework.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
-dontwarn com.parse.**
-dontwarn com.google.gsom.**

-keep public class * extends pe.gob.devida.activities.BaseActivity
-keep public class * extends pe.gob.devida.fragments.BaseFragment
# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
```

Errors occurred in classes extended of BaseActivity and BaseFragment when I use Gson.

BaseActivity.class

```
package pe.gob.devida.activities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import pe.gob.devida.volley.VolleySingleton;

import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by Diego on 14/06/2015.
 */
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private VolleySingleton singleton;
    protected RequestQueue fRequestQueue;
    private static final int TIME_OUT = 10000, NUM_RETRY = 3;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        singleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
        fRequestQueue = singleton.getRequestQueue();
        progressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
    }

    public void addToQueue(Request request) {
        onPreStartConnection();
        if (request != null) {
            request.setTag(this);
            if (fRequestQueue == null)
                fRequestQueue = singleton.getRequestQueue();
            request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(TIME_OUT, NUM_RETRY,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            fRequestQueue.add(request);
        }
    }

    public void onPreStartConnection() {
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    }

    public void onConnectionFinished() {
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    }

    public void onConnectionFailed(String error) {
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    public void makeStringRequest(int method, String url, Response.Listener<String> listener,
                                  Response.ErrorListener errorListener, final Map headers,
                                  final Map params) {
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(method, url, listener, errorListener) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                return headers;
            }

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                return params;
            }
        };
        addToQueue(request);
    }

    public void makeStringRequest(int method, String url, Response.Listener<String> listener,
                                  Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(method, url, listener, errorListener);
        addToQueue(request);
    }

    protected abstract Response.Listener getListener();
    protected abstract Response.ErrorListener getErrorListener();

}
```

BaseFragment.class

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    private VolleySingleton singleton;
    protected RequestQueue fRequestQueue;
    private static final int TIME_OUT = 10000, NUM_RETRY = 3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        singleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        fRequestQueue = singleton.getRequestQueue();
    }

    public void addToQueue(Request request) {
        if (request != null) {
            request.setTag(this);
            if (fRequestQueue == null)
                fRequestQueue = singleton.getRequestQueue();
            request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(TIME_OUT, NUM_RETRY,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            onPreStartConnection();
            fRequestQueue.add(request);
        }
    }

    public void onPreStartConnection() {
        getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    }

    public void onConnectionFinished() {
        getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    }

    public void onConnectionFailed(String error) {
        getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void makeStringRequest(int method, String url, Response.Listener<String> listener,
                                  Response.ErrorListener errorListener, final Map headers,
                                  final Map params) {
        onPreStartConnection();
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(method, url, listener, errorListener) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                return headers;
            }

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                return params;
            }
        };
    }

    public void makeStringRequest(int method, String url, Response.Listener<String> listener,
                                  Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        onPreStartConnection();
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(method, url, listener, errorListener);
        addToQueue(request);
    }

    public void makeStringRequest(int method, String url) {
        onPreStartConnection();
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(method, url, getListener(), getErrorListener());
        addToQueue(request);
    }

    protected abstract Response.Listener getListener();

    protected abstract Response.ErrorListener getErrorListener();
}
```

the Log is showed when I opened this Fragment:
CentrosFragment.class

```
public class CentrosFragment extends BaseFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    GoogleMap gMap;
    private List<MarkerOptions> list = Collections.emptyList();
    private List<Establecimiento> data = Collections.emptyList();
    private final static String URL ="http://www.eljade.com.pe/app/obtener_establecimientos.php";

    public CentrosFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 12) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_centros, container, false);
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.centrosMap);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        return root;
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        gMap = googleMap;
        gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        gMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        LatLng myPosition = new LatLng(-12.046374,
                -77.0427934);
        gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myPosition, Constant.FIRST_ZOOM));
        makeStringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL);
        /*getData();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            gMap.addMarker(list.get(i));
        }*/
    }
    @Override
    protected Response.Listener getListener() {
        return new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Establecimiento>>() {}.getType();
                data = new Gson().fromJson(response, listType);
                for (int i = 0; i<data.size(); i++){
                    gMap.addMarker(data.get(i).getMarker());
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected Response.ErrorListener getErrorListener() {
        return new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Establecimiento>>() {}.getType(); You should check here.Something might be wrong here.Or if any thread trying to reach an object created other this might cause error as well.

Comment: As I said, he apk works well when I launched since AndroidStudio. I think error is in proguard-rules.pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with this:

proguard:

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes  Signature,SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
-keep class * implements java.io.Serializable {
     static final long serialVersionUID;
     private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
     private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
     private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
     java.lang.Object writeReplace();
     java.lang.Object readResolve();
     private *;
     void set*(***);
     *** get*();
}
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
```